# How to validate CreatableSelect component (multi select) with yup (and react-form-hooks)

Tags: reactjs, react-select, yup, react-hook-form

Any idea how best to do this. The answers I found so far only relate to single value react-select components.

This is the component I am using.

```
      <CreatableSelect
        isClearable
        components={{ ClearIndicator }}
        styles={{ clearIndicator: ClearIndicatorStyles }}
        isMulti
        className='react-select-container'
        classNamePrefix="react-select"
        delimiter=","
        inputId={props.id}
        inputProps={{ name: props.name }}
        placeholder={'Please select from the list or add you own'}
        onChange={handleChange}
        onInputChange={handleInputChange}
        options={props.options}
        required={props.required}
        isOptionDisabled={(option) => isWithinLimit}
        value={selected}
        menuPlacement={props.menuPlacement}
        ref={ref}

    />
```

if props.name = "personalSkills";

This is part of the yup schema

```
yup.object().shape({
    ...
    personalSkills: yup.string().required()

});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say your options are in the form:

```
options = [{
    label: 'string',
    value: 'string'
}]
```

Then, you could define Yup schema like this:

```
Yup.array()
  .min(2, 'Pick at least two items')
  .of(
    Yup.object().shape({
      label: Yup.string().required(),
      value: Yup.string().required(),
    })
  )
```

Here is an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/jRzE53pqR

Comment: thanks for the reply. in the end I treated the list as a string and just validated it's length using vanilla javascript.

Comment: Can this work with react hook form? I'm unable to replicate it in rhf :/